# How to use the fatls command in uboot sandbox?

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

I am working uboot sandbox. here how to see my fatls in sandbox.

```
  => help fatls
  fatls - list files in a directory (default /)

  Usage:
  fatls <interface> [<dev[:part]>] [directory]
    - list files from 'dev' on 'interface' in a 'directory'
```

here what is interface and what is dev in my system.
i am trying,

```
  => fatls sda 0
  ** Bad device sda 0 **
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a bit more work.  Assuming you have built sandbox already:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=fat.img bs=1k count=2048
$ mkfs.vfat ./fat.img
$ ./u-boot
...
=> host bind 0 fat.img
=> fatls host 0:0

0 file(s), 0 dir(s)

=>
```